# High-performance JavaScript interpreter for web crawling

Tags: javascript, selenium, web-crawler, headless

I'm looking for a JS engine + DOM implementation.

It will be used to mine information for users on the web at real time. I have tried several solutions (phatomjs, zombiejs, xvfb with selenium, chrome, firefox), but all of then were too slow and hard to scale for use in real-time apps.

What is the most lightweight approach I can take? I only need the resulting DOM of a request scrapped, no need for hard interactions with the js engine.

Comment: Get a better connection.

Comment: @zerkms The connection is fine.

Comment: Define "fine". Also how exactly did you determine it's a JS that is slow (and must be optimized), not TCP?

Comment: @zerkms I meant I have several http-only web crawler running at max speed just fine. I assumed the fault is in js because of the rendering process that some engines made (not sure if all did this). Also, how would you go about optimize TCP? Any tips that may help me get it to go faster are welcome, js-related or not.

Comment: You may want to look into [`Scrapy`](http://scrapy.org/) and [`scrapyjs`](https://github.com/scrapinghub/scrapyjs) (based on `Splash`).

Comment: I'm give it a try, thanks!